Упрощение интерполяции строки
Нашел вот такую информацию. Однако меня интересует другое.
К примеру у меня есть в коде такой метод:
public static void outDebug(LogFilter type, string text, params object[] args)
{
    if (!ShouldLog(type, LogLevel.Debug))
        return;

    outMessage(type, LogLevel.Debug, text, args);
}

Я хочу минимизировать боксинги в случае когда у меня попадаются переменные - value type. Да и вообще в итоге все вызовы функций и методов сводятся к использованию вот этого метода.
Чтобы не бегать по всему коду и искать устаревшую интерполяцию типа:
Log.outDebug(LogFilter.Rbac, "RBACData.DenyPermission [Id: {0} Name: {1}] (Permission {2}, RealmId {3}). Permission does not exists",
               GetId(), GetName(), permissionId, realmId);

где у меня комбинированы строки и другие (обычно value) типы, я просто меняю параметры метода на string[]:
public static void outDebug(LogFilter type, string text, params string[] args)
{
    if (!ShouldLog(type, LogLevel.Debug))
        return;

    outMessage(type, LogLevel.Debug, text, args);
}

и получаю тонну ошибок в тех местах, где и нужно.
Однако, довольно долго вручную производить операции. IntelliSense почему-то позволяет автоматизировать только однотипные случаи, которых очень мало. Почему-то разработчики его не научили распознавать обычный формат. Я согласен, что тут можно написать любую функцию и любую последовательность аргументов, поэтому IDE не хочет принимать решение.
Однако они уже внедрили ИИ и я надеялся, что после 10-20 исправлений - ИИ сообразит что там происходит и подхватит это дело - но увы.
Может кто знает, существует ли (название) "чудо-расширения" для таких случаев?
В итоге чтобы получить автоматически вот такое:
Log.outDebug(LogFilter.Rbac, $"RBACData.DenyPermission [Id: {GetId()} Name: {GetName()}] (Permission {permissionId}, RealmId {realmId}). Permission does not exists");


Я понял, ловлю блох... Просто у меня это учебный проект, я просто занимаюсь рефакторингом ради рефакторинга, чтобы в итоге получить конфетку

а что конкретно ты хочешь менять? просто тип параметр в функции с params object[] args на params string[] args?

Желание минимизировать боксинги говорит о том, что нужна производительность. Тогда смотрим High-performance logging in .NET. И там ссылка ведёт на Compile-time logging source generation.

Я просто пояснил ход действий чтобы было понятно как я к этой проблеме пришел. Я не хотел менять систему логинга (пока что), хотел просто избавится от боксингов где это возможно, используя интерполяцию. Просто в виду огромного количества переделок - хотелось автоматизировать этот процесс. Потому что задача очень типовая - поместить аргументы в те места, где обозначены цыферками в скобочках их порядковый номер.

А обычная автозамена не справляется?

Только в очень однотипных случаях, почему-то, когда количество и название аргументов совпадает

Сам не пробовал, но читал, что в подобных ситуациях делают автозамену с регулярными выражениями. Попробуйте погуглить, может найдёте что-то подходящее.
